# Finishing 12ft x12 ft room above garage

Tags: framing

The joist are currently 2x10 spanning 21 ft with 16"oc. Will sistering 2x10s to current joist add enough strength for finished room?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but my guess is that you need an engineer on-site to safely approve or disprove this. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need 3 ply 2x10 SPF at 16" on center spacing to span 21' with only floor load on the middle 12' of the span.

If there is any roof load on these joists then that completely changes everything.